# Get Facebook video views from public video

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I am trying to implement a view counter in my website for videos I created. The current challenge: Getting the public views from facebook. Since I produced the videos for other persons, thy are not posted on my facebook site.
Therefore, the FB graph API does not work, since the *video_insights* are only visible for the pages who posted them.

But facebook publishes the views publicly under every video. Is there any opportunity I miss with the graph API or is there a workaround for it (thought about loading the posts HTML and extracting the view div, but this would violate CORS regulations...).

[FB Graph API *video_insights*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/video_insights/) syntax:

```
{video-id}/video_insights/total_video_views
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and I eventually just scraped the views using phantomjs in conjuction with shell scripting. The thing is, that i still don't know if such action is allowed by facebook at all.